# MySQL get data with table joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables. One is `ps_product_lang` and `ps_category_product`. The data inside `ps_category_product` is like this

```
id_category  id_product
2            1
2            2
2            3
2            4
2            5
2            6
2            7
3            1
3            2
3            3
3            4
3            5
3            6
3            7
4            1
4            2
5            1
7            2
8            3
8            4
8            5
8            6
8            7
9            3
10           4
```

The table for `ps_product_lang` is like this

```
id_product      id_lang     name
1               1           Faded Short Sleeves T-shirt
1               2           Faded Short Sleeves T-shirt
2               1           Blouse
2               2           Blouse
3               1           Printed Dress
3               2           Printed Dress
4               1           Printed Dress
4               2           Printed Dress
5               1           Printed Summer Dress
5               2           Printed Summer Dress
6               1           Printed Summer Dress
6               2           Printed Summer Dress
7               1           Printed Chiffon Dress
7               2           Printed Chiffon Dress
```

So here I want to get the id_product,name from ps_product_lang where id_category is 5,7 and name like  'p%'. so can someone tell me what would be the query. Any help and suggestions would be really appreceable.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `LIKE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the hint. Can you show me some code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordon was hinting, you simply need an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables, along with a where condition to restrict the product category and name:

```
SELECT t1.id_product,
       t1.name
FROM ps_product_lang t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id_product
    FROM ps_category_product
    WHERE id_category IN (5, 7)
) t2
    ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product
WHERE t1.name LIKE 'P%'
```

Here is a demo which omits the `WHERE` clause to show how the query behaves when it actually returns data:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Its showing error like 

` #1054 - Unknown column 't2.id_category' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @NewUser Sorry, I left out an alias.  By the way, the query you want won't actually return anything right now using your test data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` to get data from 2 tables

```
   SELECT p.id_product,name 
    FROM ps_product_lang p 
   JOIN ps_category_product c 
   ON p.id_product=c.id_product 
   WHERE id_category IN (5,7) 
   AND name LIKE 'p%'
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some context or text explaining what this snippet does and how it works would be nice, for future readers also.

Comment: @VDWWD OP has himself mentioned that using join and everything..So I left it as such.. Thanks..il editted :)